# GWT Add Fields Dynamically to Editor

Tags: gwt, dynamic, editor

Is it possible to dynamically construct an editor in GWT? All the examples I have seen use the uiBinder and @UiField annotation to statically define editable fields to display. If, at run time, I wanted to add in an additional field based on some settings of the application how could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to use UIBinder or without UIBinder? Can you post some code or do you ask in general?

Comment: Probably without UiBinder as I want to generate the entire form dynamically but it shouldn't matter too much. The question is asked in general, I don't have any sample code to work from but any simple editor example will suffice - what I'm interested in is the dynamic construction side. Thx.

Comment: You might be able to use [GIN](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) which is [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) for GWT...probably without UiBinder in your case.

Comment: GIN and GUICE will again be pre compilation. The question is about post gwt compilation in case screen is required to load a sequence of editors decided based on some external input like db configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Editor Framework's Code generator need to know what to be generated. It extracts that information from the declared fields of the View ( Editor ), also with the help of annotations,  to generate some supporting java classes.

> So, If you don't declare the field then Code Generator will not be
>   able to generate  supporting code for it. As a result values wouldn't
>   be get bind to Editors.
>
> But if the fields you are adding dynamically is all of the same type,
>   then you have a chance to implement this requirement using ListEditors or CompositeEditors and by creating a new Adapter for your new view (Editor) .